# How to collapse child control in listviewitem UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

Universal Windows Platform, C#

How can I collapse/expand the child listview of item MainListView listitem from code behind? I have not found anything that works.
I'd like to do this on the SelectionChanged event.

XAML

```
        <ListView x:Name="DestListView" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,60,0,0" SelectionChanged="listview_SelectionChanged" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle >
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,.5,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gainsboro" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="20" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding destination}" FontSize="20" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding total_quantity}" FontSize="20" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding package_type}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding total_weight}" FontSize="20" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    **<!--Collpase/Expand-->**

                    <ListView x:Name="DetailListView" ItemsSource="{Binding destination_data}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="20,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding visual_number}" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                  </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

CodeBehind

```
     private void listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //GET THE ITEM
        var selectItem = DestListView.Items[DestListView.SelectedIndex];

        //GET THE CHILD SOMEHOW
        //ListView childListView = (ListView)...not sure what to do here

        //if (childListView != null)
        //{
        //    if (childListView.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        //    {
        //        //childListView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        //childListView.Visibility = new Visibility;
        //    }
        //}

    }
```

Comment: The Tag should be UWP not WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i would do it.

I would create two DataTemplates one to show when selected (Expanded), another when not expanded.

Below is my **ViewModel**.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItems>();
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            MyItems item = new MyItems();
            item.Name = "Main Item " + i.ToString();
            ObservableCollection<MySubItems> subItems = new ObservableCollection<MySubItems>();
            for (int j=1;j<=5;j++)
            {
                subItems.Add(new MySubItems() { Title = "Sub Item " + j.ToString() });
            }
            item.Data = subItems;
            myItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItems> myItems { get; set; }
}

public class MyItems
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MySubItems> Data { get; set; }
}

public class MySubItems
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my **MainPage.xaml** as *requested*

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NoSelectDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NoSelectDataTemplate}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle >
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,.5,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gainsboro" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And Below is how my **SelectionChanged** Event Looks like.

```
private int PreviousIndex;
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lv = sender as ListView;

    if (PreviousIndex >=0)
    {
        ListViewItem prevItem = (lv.ContainerFromIndex(PreviousIndex)) as ListViewItem;
        prevItem.ContentTemplate = Resources["NoSelectDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    }

    ListViewItem item = (lv.ContainerFromIndex(lv.SelectedIndex)) as ListViewItem;
    item.ContentTemplate = Resources["SelectDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

    PreviousIndex = lv.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Here is the **Output**

[image]

Comment: This is an amazing example. One question, how do I implement the "MyViewModel" class. I'm new to UWP coming from winforms and webforms.

Comment: @BangBang I used `ViewModel` Just for sample here. If you want to know how ViewModel Works, You should start with MVVM. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh848246.aspx) will get you started.

Comment: thanks for the info, I've been researching MVVM. In the meantime with your example code, would it be possible to show the rest of the xaml to hook up the listview and binding ViewModel?

Comment: @BangBang Updated my answer with full MainPage.xaml.