# Collapse panel inside the content dialog using c# for UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I couldn't find any design like an accordion (collapsible panel) within the content dialog using c# for UWP app. I can't customize the button alignment, title alignment and collapsible panel within the content dialog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an accordion style content holder UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676405/how-to-make-an-accordion-style-content-holder-uwp)

Comment: inside content dialog i will show the accordion

Comment: When i click button the time content dialog open with accordion content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly put your collapsible panel in the Content of ContentDialog in xaml. And if you want to customize the button alignment, title alignment, you need to change it in the Style of ContentDialog. Take title as an example, there is a ContentControl named "Title" represents Title and change its HorizontalAlignment to "Center", it will put the Title in the center of the dialog.

.xaml:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentDialog" x:Key="ContentDialogStyle1">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentDialog">
                        <Border x:Name="Container">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DialogShowingStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition To="DialogHidden">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="1.05" />
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="1.05" />
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.083" Value="0.0" />
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition To="DialogShowing">

                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.05" />
                                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="1.0" />
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.05" />
                                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="1.0" />
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.167" Value="1.0" />
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DialogHidden" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DialogShowing">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter Target="BackgroundElement.TabFocusNavigation" Value="Cycle" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DialogShowingWithoutSmokeLayer">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DialogSizingStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DefaultDialogSizing" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FullDialogSizing">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="BackgroundElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonsVisibilityStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="AllVisible" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoneVisible">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="CommandSpace.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryVisible">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Margin" Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SecondaryVisible">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Margin" Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CloseVisible">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.Margin" Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryAndSecondaryVisible">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Margin" Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryAndCloseVisible">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.Margin" Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SecondaryAndCloseVisible">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Margin" Value="0,0,2,0" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.Margin" Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DefaultButtonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoDefaultButton" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryAsDefaultButton">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Style" Value="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SecondaryAsDefaultButton">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Style" Value="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CloseAsDefaultButton">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="CloseButton.Style" Value="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DialogBorderStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoBorder" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="AccentColorBorder">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="BackgroundElement.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>

                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush}">
                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
                  BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBorderWidth}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                  MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinWidth}"
                  MaxWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxWidth}"
                  MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinHeight}"
                  MaxHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxHeight}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform" />
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <Grid x:Name="DialogSpace" Padding="{ThemeResource ContentDialogPadding}">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScrollViewer"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      ZoomMode="Disabled"
                      Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentScrollViewerMargin}"
                      IsTabStop="False">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <ContentControl x:Name="Title"
                          Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMargin}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                          FontSize="20"
                          FontFamily="XamlAutoFontFamily"
                          FontWeight="Normal"
                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          IsTabStop="False">
                                                    <ContentControl.Template>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                MaxLines="2"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </ContentControl.Template>
                                                </ContentControl>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          FontSize="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"
                          FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                          Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMargin}"
                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                        <Grid x:Name="CommandSpace" 
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled"
                      Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogCommandSpaceMargin}">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Button x:Name="PrimaryButton"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding PrimaryButtonText}"
                        IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsPrimaryButtonEnabled}"
                        Style="{TemplateBinding PrimaryButtonStyle}"
                        ElementSoundMode="FocusOnly"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Margin="0,0,2,0"
                        Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"/>
                                            <Button x:Name="SecondaryButton"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SecondaryButtonText}"
                        IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsSecondaryButtonEnabled}"
                        Style="{TemplateBinding SecondaryButtonStyle}"
                        ElementSoundMode="FocusOnly"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Margin="2,0,2,0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                            <Button x:Name="CloseButton"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding CloseButtonText}"
                        Style="{TemplateBinding CloseButtonStyle}"
                        ElementSoundMode="FocusOnly"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Margin="2,0,0,0"
                        Grid.Column="3" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">click</Button>
        <ContentDialog x:Name="testDialog" Title="MyHeader" Style="{StaticResource ContentDialogStyle1}">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            // Add your collapsible panel

            </StackPanel>
        </ContentDialog>
    </StackPanel>
```

.cs:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await testDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```